Excel VBA giving error: Run time error 1004: method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed
I am trying to run Excel VBA code to populate all the sheets of a workbook with a formula in cell G4 of all worksheets, after obtaining a list of worksheets from a column in sheet1.
My Code is:
Sub PopulateWorksheetsWithFormula()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim formulaToFill As String
    Dim wsName As String
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim wsRange As Range

    ' Set the source sheet where the list of worksheet names is located
    Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("All Clients")
    
    ' Define the formula you want to fill in each worksheet
    formulaToFill = "=IF(AND(Sheet2!$C$2=Sheet1!C3,Sheet2!$D$2=Sheet1!D3),Sheet1!G3,"")" ' formula

    ' Find the last row in column A of the source sheet
    ' lastRow = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastRow = Range("O:O").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    ' Loop through each cell in column O
    For Each cell In sourceSheet.Range("O3:O" & lastRow)
        wsName = cell.Value ' Get the worksheet name from the cell
        
        ' Check if the worksheet exists
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wsName)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        If Not ws Is Nothing Then
            ' Fill the formula in a specific cell, e.g., G4 of the target worksheet
            ws.Range(G4).formula = formulaToFill
        Else
            ' Optionally, you can handle the case where the worksheet does not exist
            Debug.Print "Worksheet '" & wsName & "' does not exist."
        End If
        
        ' Reset the worksheet variable for the next iteration
        Set ws = Nothing
    Next cell

    MsgBox "Formulas filled in the specified worksheets."
End Sub

I'm getting the error on the following line in debug:
ws.Range(G4).formula = formulaToFill

Ive tried to change the name of the objects and worksheets, also tried to change the Range values. but to no avail.

If you know it's Range("O:O") rather than Range(O:O), surely you would know it's Range("G4"), not Range(G4)?

But when I put it as Range("G4") get error: Run time error '5': invalid procedure call or argument

No, you don't. It does not produce that error. It will produce another, different, runtime error 1004, because you need to fix your formula, like explained in the duplicate.

I forgot to mention, I am using using Excel of Mac. I'm running this on a MacBook Air

I don't have access to Office on Mac, maybe that version produces the error 5, although I would be surprised if it did, as it would be very unhelpful. Still, it is the right thing to do to put the quotes around G4, and fix the quotes in the formula like shown in the duplicate. If you have done that, and the error still persists, please edit your question to show the current fixed code that you are using that causes the error.
